# How we change content of WebView

Tags: ios

I want to change the content of web view when user click bold,italic,underline corresponding the change value get in html string. I am implementing this code .It change on view but how we get the change value in html. I am newer in iOS. Please help.Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"canperfom Action:called");

   NSLog(@"canPerformAction: called");
    NSLog(@" action %@", NSStringFromSelector(action));

    if (action == @selector(_showTextStyleOptions:)) {
        NSLog(@"hello");




        return  NO;

    }

    if (action==@selector(toggleBoldface:)) {
        NSLog(@"bye");
            return  NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{


    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];

    NSString *js = @"var styleNode = document.createElement('style');\n"
    "styleNode.type = 'text/css';\n"
    "var styleText = document.createTextNode('a {-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}');\n"
    "styleNode.appendChild(styleText);\n"
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleNode);\n";
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

NSString *tempMailBodyString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myTextView.text];
              NSString * htmlString = [Globals replaceRegex:@"(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))" : tempMailBodyString : [NSString stringWithFormat:@" $1$2 "]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do is, when a button is clicked, you inject the javascript and add the style to the html as you did in webViewDidFinishLoad: , they you have to load the modified html to the webView. But I think you are using  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: wrong. It only returns the modified HTML and you have to load it back to the webview as

```
returnedHTMLString = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
[theWebView loadHTMLString:returnedHTMLString baseURL:nil];
```